# how to build xml in cucumber

Tags: java, xml, testing, junit, cucumber

I am currently writing tests which need to read the value from XML for information then build the request. These tests are in junit.  I am writing tests to order errors so each XML will have an error and the test will show the correct error code.

I want to find the way for the XML to be separate from the test. For each test, I write I don't want to build new XML.  Is there a way I can put the XML for each test in a separate folder?

currently, this is the way I am building the XML below and this is done for each test.  It feels repetitive and there should be a better way of doing this.

```
private <T> T readValueFromXml(ResponseEntity<String> response, String xpathExpression,
      Function<String, T> parser)
      throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBody().getBytes()));
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(xpathExpression).evaluate(xmlDocument,
        XPathConstants.NODESET);
    if (nodeList.getLength() != 1) {
      LOG.warn("Found {} nodes for {}", nodeList.getLength(), xpathExpression);
    }
    return parser.apply(nodeList.item(0).getTextContent());
  }


  private RequestEntity<String> buildRequest(URI orderUri, String body) {
    Signature submitSignature = auth.generateExpectedSignature(orderUri,
        Collections.singletonMap("h1", "bla"),
        secret, keyId, "hmac-sha256");

    RequestEntity<String> request = RequestEntity.post(orderUri)
        .header(AUTHORIZATION, submitSignature.toString())
        .header(CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
        .header(ACCEPT, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE)
        .header("h1", "bla")
        .body(body);
    LOG.debug("{} {}", request.getMethod(), request.getUrl());
    LOG.debug("headers: {}", request.getHeaders());
    return request;
  }

  private URI orderUri(String orderToken) {
    String uri = SBUX_DPI_SERVICE_URI + "order/" + orderToken;
    return URI.create(uri);
  }

  private URI totalsUri(String orderToken) {
    String uri = SBUX_DPI_SERVICE_URI + "totals/" + orderToken;
    return URI.create(uri);
  }

  /**
   * Request containing SH AMERICANO w/ Nonfat milk and Extra Caramel Syrup
   */
  private String priceOrderXml(String orderToken) {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>\n"
        + "<priceOrder>\n"
        + "    <storeNumber>" + STORE_NUMBER + "</storeNumber>\n"
        + "    <dateTime>2020-01-21T16:00:25Z</dateTime>\n"
        + "    <orderToken>" + orderToken + "</orderToken>\n"
        + "    <subChannelType>mobile</subChannelType>\n"
        + "    <user>\n"
        + "        <currentTierNumber>1</currentTierNumber>\n"
        + "        <displayName>Jim Jones</displayName>\n"
        + "        <partnerNumber>PARTNER1</partnerNumber>\n"
        + "    </user>\n"
        + "    <cart>\n"
        + "        <items>\n"
        + "            <item>\n"
        + "                <qty>1</qty>\n"
        + "                <sku>\n"
        + "                    <code>93</code>\n"
        + "                </sku>\n"
        + "                <childItems>\n"
        + "                  <childItem>\n"
        + "                    <qty>2</qty>\n"
        + "                    <sku>\n"
        + "                      <code>159778</code>\n"
        + "                    </sku>\n"
        + "                  </childItem>\n"
        + "                  <childItem>\n"
        + "                    <qty>1</qty>\n"
        + "                    <sku>\n"
        + "                      <code>109840</code>\n"
        + "                    </sku>\n"
        + "                  </childItem>\n"
        + "                </childItems>"
        + "            </item>\n"
        + "        </items>\n"
        + "        <promotions/>\n"
        + "        <delivery/>\n"
        + "        <preparation>ConsumeInStore</preparation>\n"
        + "    </cart>\n"
        + "</priceOrder>";
  }

  private String submitOrderXml(String orderToken) {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\" ?>\n"
        + "<submitOrder>\n"
        + "    <storeNumber>" + STORE_NUMBER + "</storeNumber>\n"
        + "    <dateTime>2020-01-21T16:00:25Z</dateTime>\n"
        + "    <orderToken>" + orderToken + "</orderToken>\n"
        + "    <subChannelType>mobile</subChannelType>\n"
        + "    <orderPrintType>1</orderPrintType>\n"
        + "    <user>\n"
        + "        <currentTierNumber>1</currentTierNumber>\n"
        + "        <displayName>Jim Jones</displayName>\n"
        + "        <partnerNumber>PARTNER1</partnerNumber>\n"
        + "    </user>\n"
        + "    <cart>\n"
        + "        <items>\n"
        + "            <item>\n"
        + "                <qty>1</qty>\n"
        + "                <sku>\n"
        + "                    <code>93</code>\n"
        + "                </sku>\n"
        + "                <childItems>\n"
        + "                  <childItem>\n"
        + "                    <qty>1</qty>\n"
        + "                    <sku>\n"
        + "                      <code>159778</code>\n"
        + "                    </sku>\n"
        + "                  </childItem>\n"
        + "                  <childItem>\n"
        + "                    <qty>1</qty>\n"
        + "                    <sku>\n"
        + "                      <code>109840</code>\n"
        + "                    </sku>\n"
        + "                  </childItem>\n"
        + "                </childItems>"
        + "            </item>\n"
        + "        </items>\n"
        + "        <promotions/>\n"
        + "        <delivery/>\n"
        + "        <preparation>ConsumeInStore</preparation>\n"
        + "    </cart>\n"
        + "          <payment>\n"
        + "              <tender>\n"
        + "                  <type>SVC</type>\n"
        + "                  <cardNumber>1111222233334444</cardNumber>\n"
        + "                  <amountToCharge>1990</amountToCharge>\n"
        + "              </tender>\n"
        + "          </payment>\n"
        + "</submitOrder>";
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to put in a folder? Are you writing tests in different classes or one class?

Comment: @komatiraju032  Hi! I am writing different tests which require different XML.  It looks messy, I just wanted it to look a lot neater.  Tests are written in one class at the moment